# how to create a interrupt service function in c for real time linux operating system?

Tags: c, linux, udp, interrupt, isr

Scenario : Client is sending a data and the server is receving the data from client via ethernet layer (udp). When the server receives a data from the client on the ip layer (kernel). It interrupts the kernel and kernel as to execute the data by the client, so 
I want to create a interrupt service function to catch the interrupt from the network service card.

could someone help me how to go about it ?

Comment: Which part is real-time?

Comment: server is real time operating system

Comment: It may be useful to say what real-time operating system it is!

Comment: real time linux or qnx real time operating system

Comment: so you want to read network data directly from the ethernet card instead of relying on the built-in drivers to do it for you?

Comment: Network card will interrupt the linux or qnx kernel. I have to handle this interrupt - could you tell me how ?? I already created a ethernet interface and it is receving the data but when server receives the data from the client the server client should stop what it is doing and start execute this.

Comment: Well, set a semaphore in the interrupt-handler and request a reschedule on exit.  The server client thread waits on the semaphore.  Something like that, anyway.  Linux drivers have a well-defined structure, don't they?

Comment: I am using rt linux and someone can give me a small example for this ?

Comment: @user3458454 I doubt it because interrupt handlers, loading vectors and configuring interrupt-controllers is hardware-specific.

Comment: I am using x86 target.

Comment: Since you want the code to be run on both QNX and RTLinux (you meant RTLinux by real-time Linux, right?) you have to write in standard POSIX and be very careful, since for QNX it would be compiled as a user-space application and on RTLinux it's a kernel module. That said, you should be looking on how (and if, since I'm not sure) you can install an ISR through the POSIX API.

Comment: QNX and RT linux is a microkernel - isnt it ??

Comment: Yes, but to write code using RTLinux you need to code in kernel space and with kernel modules. With QNX, you can't write kernel modules (the kernel is not open) and you have real-time in user-space. I may be mistaken, but that was my understanding.

Comment: Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) notably about `SIGIO` and [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Is it possible to use poll ?? my requirement is that I am receiving a data from client on ethernet layer and network interface card interrupts the hardware- I should have the interrupt service routine to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Like Alnitak above, I question that you really want to bypass the networking services of your operating system(s), which are real-time after all. So, I suggest you follow Basile Starynkevitch's advice and use `poll`, `select` or even just `recv` from a task with adequate scheduling policy and priority.